# Only including data that has been entered

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

At the present point I have my code that is pulling data from the database using

`$this->model->function()->value;` in the controller and then being transferred via the `$data['value'] = "";` into my view were then I have a list echoing out the values that is given by the database.

What is the best way to only include the data that has been entered by the client.  Some won't add in a fax number so why should this be added to the document etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your controller is passing the attributes from your model straight over to your view you could check for the presence of the data in the view before you print the field:

```
<?php if (strlen($fax_num) > 0) { echo 'Fax number: ' . $fax_num; } ?>
```

Views can contain *some* presentation logic to determine what and how information should be displayed given the data provided.